# Co-partitioned joins in spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Are there any implementations of Spark SQL DataSources that offer Co-partition joins - most likely via the CoGroupRDD?  I did not see any uses within the existing Spark codebase.

The motivation would be to greatly reduce the shuffle traffic in the case that two tables have the same number and same ranges of partitioning keys: in that case there would be a **Mx1** instead of an **MxN** shuffle fanout.

The only large-scale implementation of joins presently in Spark SQL seems to be ***ShuffledHashJoin*** - which *does* require the MxN shuffle fanout and thus is expensive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [Bucket Join optimization](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11512) that should be coming in Spark 2.0.

In 1.6 you can accomplish something similar, but only by caching the data. [SPARK-4849](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4849)

Comment: Thanks Michael. Looking forward to the bucket join.