# Worker Behavior with two (or more) dataframes having the same key

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, partitioning, parquet

I'm using PySpark (Spark 1.4.1) in a cluster.  I have two DataFrames each containing the same key values but different data for the other fields.

I partitioned each DataFrame separately using the key and wrote a parquet file to HDFS.  I then read the parquet file back into memory as a new DataFrame.  If I join the two DataFrames, will the processing for the join happen on the same workers?

For example:

- `dfA` contains {`userid`, `firstname`, `lastname`}  partitioned by `userid`
- `dfB` contains {`userid`, `activity`, `job`, `hobby`} partitioned by `userid`

```py
dfC = dfA.join(dfB, dfA.userid==dfB.userid)
```

Is `dfC` already partitioned by `userid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is `dfC` already partitioned by `userid`

The answer depends on what you mean by *partitioned*. Records with the same `userid` should be located on the same partition, but `DataFrames` don't support partitioning understood as having a `Partitioner`. Only the `PairRDDs` (`RDD[(T, U)]`) can have partitioner in Spark. It means that for most applications the answer is no. Neither `DataFrame` or underlaying `RDD` is partitioned.

You'll find more details about `DataFrames` and partitioning in [How to define partitioning of DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30995699/1560062) Another question you can follow is [Co-partitioned joins in spark SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850596/co-partitioned-joins-in-spark-sql).

> If I join the two `DataFrames`, will the processing for the join happen on the same workers?

Once again it depends on what you mean. Records with the same `userid` have to be transfered to the same node before transformed rows can be yielded. I ask if it is guaranteed to happen without any network traffic the answer is no.

To be clear it would be exactly the same even if `DataFrame` had a partitioner. Data co-partitioning is not equivalent to data co-location. It simply means that `join` operation can be performed using one-to-one mapping not shuffling. You can find more in [Daniel Darbos'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3318517/daniel-darabos) answer to [Does a join of co-partitioned RDDs cause a shuffle in Apache Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28399685/1560062).