# Understanding SparkSQL and its usage of partitioning

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to evaluate Spark SQL for some data manipulation queries.  The scenario I'm interested in this this:

```
table1: key, value1, value2
table2: key, value3, value4

create table table3 as
select * from table1 join table2 on table1.key = table2.key
```

It sounds like I should be able to create the table1 and table2 RDDs (but I don't see a very obvious example of that in the docs).
But the bigger question is this -- if I have successfully partitioned the 2 table RDDs by key and then go to join them with Spark SQL, will it be smart enough to take advantage of the partitioning?  And if I create a new RDD as a result of that join, will it also be partitioned?  In other words, will it be completely shuffle-free?
I would really appreciate pointers to documentation and or examples on these subjects.

Comment: Hm this might be dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850596/co-partitioned-joins-in-spark-sql?rq=1 but I would appreciate links to discussions or examples too...

Comment: Do you mean http://stackoverflow.com/q/30995699/1560062?

Answer (score 4):

If you mean conversions between `RDDs` and `Datasets` then the answer to both question is negative.

RDD partitioning is defined only for `RDD[(T, U)]` and will be lost after `RDD` is converted to a `Dataset`. There are some cases when you can benefit per-existing data layout but `join` is not one of these especially that `RDDs` and `Datasets` use different hashing techniques (standard `hashCode` and `MurmurHash` respectively. You can of course mimic the latter one by defining custom partitioner `RDD` but it is not really the point).

Similarly information about partitioning is lost when `Dataset` is converted to `RDD`.

You can use `Dataset` partitioning to which can be used to optimize `joins` though. For example if tables have been pre-partitioned:

```scala
val n: Int = ??? 

val df1 =  Seq(
  ("key1", "val1", "val2"), ("key2", "val3", "val4")
).toDF("key", "val1", "val2").repartition(n, $"key").cache

val df2 = Seq(
  ("key1", "val5", "val6"), ("key2", "val7", "val8")
).toDF("key", "val3", "val4").repartition(n, $"key").cache
```

subsequent `join` based on the `key` won't require additional exchange.

```scala
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", -1

df1.explain
// == Physical Plan ==
// InMemoryTableScan [key#171, val1#172, val2#173]
//    +- InMemoryRelation [key#171, val1#172, val2#173], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
//          +- Exchange hashpartitioning(key#171, 3)
//             +- LocalTableScan [key#171, val1#172, val2#173]
```

```scala
df2.explain
// == Physical Plan ==
// InMemoryTableScan [key#201, val3#202, val4#203]
//    +- InMemoryRelation [key#201, val3#202, val4#203], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
//          +- Exchange hashpartitioning(key#201, 3)
//             +- LocalTableScan [key#201, val3#202, val4#203]
//
```

```scala
df1.join(df3, Seq("key")).explain
// == Physical Plan ==
// *Project [key#171, val1#172, val2#173, val5#232, val6#233]
// +- *SortMergeJoin [key#171], [key#231], Inner
//    :- *Sort [key#171 ASC], false, 0
//    :  +- *Filter isnotnull(key#171)
//    :     +- InMemoryTableScan [key#171, val1#172, val2#173], [isnotnull(key#171)]
//    :           +- InMemoryRelation [key#171, val1#172, val2#173], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
//    :                 +- Exchange hashpartitioning(key#171, 3)
//    :                    +- LocalTableScan [key#171, val1#172, val2#173]
//    +- *Sort [key#231 ASC], false, 0
//       +- *Filter isnotnull(key#231)
//          +- InMemoryTableScan [key#231, val5#232, val6#233], [isnotnull(key#231)]
//                +- InMemoryRelation [key#231, val5#232, val6#233], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
//                      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(key#231, 3)
//                         +- LocalTableScan [key#231, val5#232, val6#233]
```

Obviously we don't really benefit from that on a single join. So it makes sense only if a single table is used for multiple `joins`.

Also Spark can benefit from the partitioning created by `join` so if we wanted to perform another `join`:

```scala
val df3 = Seq(
  ("key1", "val9", "val10"), ("key2", "val11", "val12")
).toDF("key", "val5", "val6")

df1.join(df3, Seq("key")).join(df3, Seq("key"))
```

we would benefit from the structure created by the first operation (note `ReusedExchange`):

```scala
// == Physical Plan ==
// *Project [key#171, val1#172, val2#173, val5#682, val6#683, val5#712, val6#713]
// +- *SortMergeJoin [key#171], [key#711], Inner
//    :- *Project [key#171, val1#172, val2#173, val5#682, val6#683]
//    :  +- *SortMergeJoin [key#171], [key#681], Inner
//    :     :- *Sort [key#171 ASC], false, 0
//    :     :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(key#171, 200)
//    :     :     +- *Filter isnotnull(key#171)
//    :     :        +- InMemoryTableScan [key#171, val1#172, val2#173], [isnotnull(key#171)]
//    :     :              +- InMemoryRelation [key#171, val1#172, val2#173], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
//    :     :                    +- Exchange hashpartitioning(key#171, 3)
//    :     :                       +- LocalTableScan [key#171, val1#172, val2#173]
//    :     +- *Sort [key#681 ASC], false, 0
//    :        +- Exchange hashpartitioning(key#681, 200)
//    :           +- *Project [_1#677 AS key#681, _2#678 AS val5#682, _3#679 AS val6#683]
//    :              +- *Filter isnotnull(_1#677)
//    :                 +- LocalTableScan [_1#677, _2#678, _3#679]
//    +- *Sort [key#711 ASC], false, 0
//       +- ReusedExchange [key#711, val5#712, val6#713], Exchange hashpartitioning(key#681, 200)
```

Comment: So this is example with DataSet, that's good.  Will this map to SparkSql?  What if I create a new DF using Spark SQL by joining 2 DFs partitioned on the same column?  Will the resulting DF be partitioned?

Comment: Yes, there is no execution difference between SQL and `DataFrame` API.

Comment: and my understanding is that it will only be smart in Spark 2.0, right?

Comment: As far as I remember basic optimizations should work in 1.6 as well but for full benefits you'll need 2.0+