# Spark: best practice on memory-heavy join operations

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I have a spark program which involves join operations on big Hive tables (millions of rows with hundreds of columns).
The memory used during these joins is really high. I would like to understand the best way to handle this scenario in Spark on YARN in a way that the job will complete succesfully without memory errors. The cluster is composed by 7 workers with 110 GB of ram and 16 cores each.
Consider the following scala code:

```
object Model1Prep {

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Modello1_Spark")
        conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
        conf.set("spark.io.compression.codec", "org.apache.spark.io.LZFCompressionCodec")
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
        val hc = new HiveContext(sc)
        import hc.implicits._


        hc.sql("SET hive.exec.compress.output=true")
        hc.sql("SET parquet.compression=SNAPPY")
        hc.sql("SET spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec=snappy")


        // loading tables on dataframes
        var tableA = hc.read.table("TA")
        var tableB = hc.read.table("TB")
        var tableC = hc.read.table("TC")
        var tableD = hc.read.table("TD")


        // registering tables
        tableA.registerTempTable("TA")
        tableB.registerTempTable("TB")
        tableC.registerTempTable("TC")
        tableD.registerTempTable("TD")


        var join1 = hc.sql("""
            SELECT 
                [many fields]
            FROM TA a 
            JOIN TB b ON a.field = b.field      
            LEFT JOIN TC c ON a.field = c.field         
            WHERE [conditions]
        """)


        var join2 = hc.sql("""
            SELECT 
                [many fields]
            FROM TA a 
            LEFT JOIN TD d ON a.field = d.field
            WHERE [conditions]
        """)


        // [other operations]


        sc.close()
    }
}
```

Considering that the join operations are really expensive on memory, what are my best options here?
I know that a dataframe can be persisted both on memory and on disk, possibly using serialization to be more compact in memory at cost of slower processing time for deserialization (more on [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html) and [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence)).
From the code above, the table TA is used in both joins so it makes sense to persist it:

```
    //[...]        

    // persisting
    tableA.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2)

    // registering tables
    tableA.registerTempTable("TA")
    tableB.registerTempTable("TB")
    tableC.registerTempTable("TC")
    tableD.registerTempTable("TD")

    //[...]
```

Should I also persist the other tables in the same way? Or are there other things to make this code run and complete smoothly?

Answer (score 0):

If you know which field you're joining on and it's always the same field then, [as this SO answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28399685/10192395), use the same partitioner for the joined tables.