# How to properly apply HashPartitioner before a join in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, partitioner

To reduce shuffling during the joining of two RDDs, I decided to partition them using HashPartitioner first. Here is how I do it. Am I doing it correctly, or is there a better way to do this?

```
val rddA = ...
val rddB = ...

val numOfPartitions = rddA.getNumPartitions

val rddApartitioned = rddA.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(numOfPartitions))
val rddBpartitioned = rddB.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(numOfPartitions))

val rddAB = rddApartitioned.join(rddBpartitioned)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> To reduce shuffling during the joining of two RDDs,

It is surprisingly common misconception that repartitoning reduces or even eliminates shuffles. *It doesn't*. Repartitioning *is shuffle* in its purest form. It doesn't save time, bandwidth or memory.

The rationale behind using proactive partitioner is different - it allows you *to shuffle once*, and reuse the state, to perform multiple by-key operations, without additional shuffles (though as far as I am aware, not necessarily without additional network traffic, [as co-partitioning doesn't imply co-location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28399685/10938362), excluding cases where shuffles occurred in a single actions).

So your code is correct, but in a case where you join once it doesn't buy you anything.

Comment: Good observation :) In my case, I also do a sortByKey afterwards, so I guess its helping.

Comment: If `sortByKey` is applied on `rddAB`, then it makes no difference at all. If it is applied on `rddApartitioned` / `rddBpartitioned` then it could provide some benefits.

Comment: @user10938362 Does it require both RDDs to be `partitionBy`ed? What happen if I only `partitionBy` for `rddA` and not `rddB`?

Answer (score 0):

Just one comment, better to append `.persist()` after `.partitionBy` if there are multiple actions for `rddApartitioned` and `rddBpartitioned`, otherwise, all the actions will evaluate the entire lineage of `rddApartitioned` and `rddBpartitioned`, which will cause the hash-partitioning takes place again and again.

```
val rddApartitioned = rddA.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(numOfPartitions)).persist()
val rddBpartitioned = rddB.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(numOfPartitions)).persist()
```