# Join two big tables with Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to join 2 very big tables by specific mutual key using Spark, I try to understand what is the optimal way to do that.

Let's say, for the example:

- table 1 contains 900M rows and ~100 columns
- table 2 contains 600M rows and ~200 columns.
- We can't use "broadcast join", the tables are big and can't be broadcast.

I want to join (inner join) the tables using the mutual 'id' columns that exists in both of them, in addition, I know that the id columns contains the same values in both of the tables, there is no id value that exists in one but doesn't exist in the other.

**The ideal way I can think of is to "divide" each one of my tables into partitions/buckets that contains the same 'id' values and to send them to the same executor that will calculate the join result with minimum data shuffling in the cluster.**

My questions are:

1. If I use for example .repartition(5, 'id') for each one of the tables - each one of the 5 partitions will contain the same 'id' values? (as long as we have the same 'id' values in both of them)

for example:

```
df1
+---+---+------+
|age| id|  name|
+---+---+------+
|  5|  1| David|
| 50|  2|  Lily|
| 10|  3|   Dan|
| 15|  4|Nicole|
| 16|  5|  Dana|
| 19|  6|   Ron|
| 20|  7| Alice|
| 22|  8|  Nora|
| 45|  9|  Sara|
| 70| 10| Aaron|
+---+---+------+


df2
+---+-----+
| id|price|
+---+-----+
|  1| 30.8|
|  1| 40.3|
|  2|100.0|
|  2| 30.1|
|  3| 99.0|
|  3|102.0|
|  4| 81.2|
|  4| 91.2|
|  5| 73.4|
|  6| 22.2|
|  7|374.4|
|  8|669.7|
|  9|  4.8|
| 10|35.38|
+---+-----+

df1.repartition(5,'id')
df2.repartition(5,'id')
```

If df1 partitions are: [id=1,id=2],[id=3,id=4],[id=5,id=6],[id=7,id=8],[id=9,id=10]

Is it necessarily be the same for df2?

2. If I use 'bucketBy' in the same way, will I get the same 'id' values in the buckets of the tables?
3. Will spark send the right partitions to the same executor? I mean, the partition that contains [id=1,id=2] of table 1 and the partition that contains [id=1,id=2] for table 2 will be sent to the same executor for the join.

If I miss something, or you can recommend another way to join 2 big tables under the assumptions I mentioned, it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55280218/8913360).
TLDR: If you want to join them once and its the only aim for re-partitioning, just simply join them.

Comment: Hi, thanks.
So, if there anything smart I can do to "help" the execution plan and to reduce shuffle if I join 2 big tables only once? I'm asking because sometimes I see a lot of shuffle in cluster that fails my jobs, and I try to restructure the data before in a way that reduce shuffle.

Comment: I guess spark chooses the best strategy, so if your cluster fails to run it you have two options left: 1- scaling up. 2- break you task into smaller ones, it takes more time to run but it would. for example you can filter both tables on the id%10==0 and perform join on them and store result, then id%10==2 etc. @nofar